# Need to know the Good way of HTML form for Entry and Edit

Tags: php, html

I am doing job in a company and works with `PHP-MySQL` also do the HTML as well. Always I use the same form for entry and edit. But some of my team mate says that you need to use different form for these two works.

I want to know what is the good and standard way to do these? Please help me, I use stack for a long time but just started questioning.

Comment: It doesn't Matter since you are probably editing what you entered in the first place. All that matters is the way you process the forms in server side

Comment: after the user enters the data; where do you process the entered or edited data? Same page or a different script?

Comment: I made my own framework for my work, all the interactions goes through the `index.php` page and the updates or entries query are in different page

Comment: you can go with any existing framework. framework will have own slandered.

Comment: sometimes there's a requirement for the editable fields to be different to those used when creating, or for different users to have the ability to change different fields. If you don't have that complexity then it's probably ok to use the same form for both entry and edit, as long as the server-side can understand whether to do an insert or update. Sounds like you have got it working already so that's not a problem.

Comment: @ADyson, Yes my projects goes well and i just need to know the actual fact. Thanks for your compliment.